# app for typing with your PC keyboard

Tags: applications

Is there a app or something for android that let's you type through your PC on your device? Pecking on your small android screen seems so painful, I'd really prefer if a hostspot or wifi connected  existed that let you type from your computer's keyboard.

Comment: You can use scrcpy on your PC. It can show you screen content as well as allows you to send your keystrokes back to Android. Works pretty well.

Comment: You can simulate entered text on-device via adb: `adb input text "<text to be typed here>"`

Comment: Take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use a bluetooth keyboard but you can connect any USB keyboard to your phone or tablet with the correct adapter and no app is required.

Comment: I see. But, I would prefer software solution if possible